# Why nginx is returning error 504 timeout even if in my nginx.conf all the properties are setted

Tags: php, apache, nginx

```
user www-data;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 500;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.domain;

    log_format isp '$bytes_sent $request_length';
    server {

        client_header_timeout 10m;
        client_body_timeout 10m;
        send_timeout 10m;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10m;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 900;
        proxy_read_timeout 500;
        proxy_connect_timeout 500;

        client_max_body_size 500m;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        listen MY_IP_ADRESS;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;




        set $root_path /var/www/mysite/data/www/mysite.com;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            root $root_path;
            access_log /var/www/nginx-logs/mysite isp;
            access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.access.log ;
            error_page 404 = @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_redirect http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_redirect http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ^~ /webstat/ {
            auth_basic "Restricted area";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/mysite/data/etc/68420649.passwd;
            try_files $uri @fallback;
        }
        include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.inc;
    }
    server {
        server_name shop.mysite.com www.shop.mysite.com;
        listen MY_IP_ADRESS;
        charset UTF-8;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
        set $root_path /var/www/mysite/data/www/shop.mysite.com;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            root $root_path;
            access_log /var/www/nginx-logs/mysite isp;
            access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/shop.mysite.com.access.log ;
            error_page 404 = @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_redirect http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_redirect http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ^~ /webstat/ {
            auth_basic "Restricted area";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/mysite/data/etc/68813297.passwd;
            try_files $uri @fallback;
        }
        include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.inc;
    }
    server {
        server_name loto.mysite.com www.loto.mysite.com;
        listen MY_IP_ADRESS;
        charset UTF-8;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
        set $root_path /var/www/mysite/data/www/loto.mysite.com;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            root $root_path;
            access_log /var/www/nginx-logs/mysite isp;
            access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/loto.mysite.com.access.log ;
            error_page 404 = @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_redirect http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_redirect http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADRESS:81;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ^~ /webstat/ {
            auth_basic "Restricted area";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/mysite/data/etc/68813303.passwd;
            try_files $uri @fallback;
        }
        include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.inc;
    }
}
```

here I've putted all the configs I cut find, but I still getting an 504 timeout error on uploading a file about 20 megabytes, its less than 2 minutes, can you look at these settings and tell me what I'am missing?, I've restarted the server after putting all this, but didn't helped, please help! Ican't upload files

Comment: this is not a valid config, please show all configuration. Are you using PHP through FCGI or nginx is proxy for apache?

Comment: code updated, thats my full config nginx, php throug fcgi

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You need to configure `fastcgi_read_timeout` in your `location` scopes.

```
location {
     ... 
     fastcgi_read_timeout 900s; # 15 minutes
     ...
}
```

Also what you can do to clean up your config (this is optional) is you can putt all the proxy_set_headers along with timeout in e.g. `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_settings`:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
```

Then you can remove all the `proxy_set_header` so you do not have to repeat them, and put this instead of them:

```
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_settings
```

That will make your config easier to maintain.

**Old Answer**
These variables must be defined in `server` scope, not in `http` scope. Also, if you are proxying to php, you also need to set

```
proxy_read_timeout 120;
proxy_connect_timeout 120;
```

If you are still having problems, please provide full configuration.

Comment: I've updated the code, here you can see all my config, I've tried to move those configs into the server {} block, but still didn't worked, thanks in advance

Comment: is there something I'am missing? I've googled all of this properties, but the server still returning 504 timeout on file uploading 20 megabytes of size, I've putted all that in server scope, but nothing of that helped, I can't understand whats wrong...of course I've restarted apache and nginx after all this changes, any help plaese

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting in your browser?

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out, if I upload a file less than 5 megabytes its all ok, but if more I get that error, the php file upload size and post size properties are also setted to 500mb

Comment: unfortunally I still get that error, I don't know which should I use in my ispmanager, php as CGI, php as FASTCGI or php as apache module? both gives me that error, but if I set as FASTCGI I get an internal server error after upload...